# Using Two Different Databases in a Node.js App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have a sails.js app that has, amongst others, a Users model and an Apartments mode. I would like to store the users the relational database, and the apartments in a document database like Mongo.

Do you think that would negatively affect performance in anyway, for example, when using Waterline to fetch the full data of the user who owns an apartment? If not, is it even a good idea at all?

Comment: Store the data where it makes sense - the ORM comes second. If Waterline doesn't work for you (it just might) just swap it out for something that does.

Comment: As above but i think that it depends on a few things... The biggest part would be latency on the network if the databases are remote as it affects directly the time to reach the end result in each case. Depends on volumes or what kind of hardware you're running too. I think there are so many things that could affect performance and those would need to be addressed before you think about how the software is dealing with the connections... In reality and in this day and age, it should be fine. Sails lets you use of multiple connections for the same reasons. I use Mysql + Elastic Search in Sails.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess what I simply was inquiring about is whether the fact that I would have data stored in two database engines simultaneously was bad practice. Obviously not.